# Why do most Ruby/Rack apps bootstrap this way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I'm trying to find a written explanation as to why many Ruby apps follow this pattern w/r/t Rack:

```
config.ru -> loads 'environment'
'environment' -> loads 'application'
'application' -> loads 'boot'
```

This is well-worn in Rails apps, but I see the same pattern in non-Rails things (e.g. Grape API apps, etc.) but I don't understand why it happens in this order.  Why does environment load application and not vice-versa?  What advantages are there to not combining application+boot into a single file?  Are there suggestions/rules as to what should go into each "bucket"?

The Rails docs talk about all these files as part of the Rails startup, but it completely ignores the rationale behind what this structure provides.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is history/tradition and how Rack itself works. Rack is very minimal interface.

> To use Rack, provide an "app": an object that responds to the call
>   method, taking the environment hash as a parameter, and returning an
>   Array with three elements:
>
> - The HTTP response code
> - A Hash of headers
> - The response body, which must respond to `#each`

The simplest possible rack app is just:

```
run Proc.new { |env| ['200', {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, ['Hello World']] }
```

Lets look at what these three files actually do:

- `config/environment.rb` is actually responsible for starting the rails application and giving Rack something which it can actually run. In a simple rack app this is usually where you would do much of the configuration and handle different environments. This is no longer the case with Rails though as it is handled upstream in the framework.
- `config/application.rb` ties together the different parts of rails by requiring railties. Its also a place where application authors can add universal configuration. The tradition is that this declares the actual application object which is run by rack while `environment.rb` is more procedural. If you where building a Rack app/framework from scratch this would be where you require your `/lib` files.
- `config/boot.rb` loads the non-rails dependencies (gems) by using Bundler. This happens very early so that rails itself can use dependencies like Nokogiri.

Could this be merged into a single file? Yes. But having each file do a single task works well. Each file did actually also have substantially more code at one point in time. For example loading dependencies before Bundler came along was a real mess.

Comment: Take a look at [sinatra's codebase](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb) if you want to see a very different approach at the same problem. IMHO its a steaming mess though.